# not been able to read the output

Tags: linux, bash

I'm not able to read the output from the cat/etc/issue and use it to check if you are using the tested distro for one of my tools

```
#!/bin/bash
cat /etc/issue 
read distro   
echo $distro
if [[ "$distro" = "Debian GNU/Linux bookworm/sid \n \l" ]];
then
 echo "You are using Debian"
else
 echo "you are not using Debian some things may not work"
fi
```

Comment: This approach is not sound.  Don't test systems, test features.  Instead of assuming that any Debian system will provide the features you need, you should test to see if the feature you want is available.   Doing this is often only slightly more challenging, but is far more robust.

Comment: What do you mean by "not able to read the output"? It's illegible to you? Or it doesn't output anything at all? Or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cat` and `read` in your current script are completely independent.

Try `read distro </etc/issue` instead.

That said, `grep` is probably better suited to figure out if something contains a certain string, and `/etc/os-release` seems like a better source for what OS you're running.

Comment: the solution read distro </etc/issue works, but how would I do it with grep?

Comment: Something like `if grep -q Debian /etc/issue; then ...`